# media query strange behavior

Tags: css, media-queries

I am attaching media query to my html document like this

```
<!-- SmartPhone CSS --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="smartphone-portrait.css" />

<!-- IPAD CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad-portrait.css"         media="only screen and (min-width : 550px)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad-landscape.css"        media="only screen and (min-width : 970px)"/>
```

smartphone-portrait.css is common file that shld be applied all the time, but if window size is smaller than 550px no style is applied see first screen.

If the window size is larger than 550 then style is applied. Why css is not being applied when window size is smaller?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your markup looks correct.  Is your problem something silly like a typo?  Maybe the ipad css's have the correct spelling and the common one is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: no typo mistake.. on ipad after a couple of orientation changed css start working

Comment: Is the problem with the ipad-portrait.css?  if so then it might be because you have the portrait set to a min-width of 550px.  That is requiring the width to be bigger than 550px.

Comment: If you want to send me your CSS files and the markup I will take a look.